# GLSL shaders render white-box only

Tags: three.js

These are my first, baby steps. I have a shader code that was working in another context (GlslCanvas.js). It worked with just FragmentShader (no vertex shader at all). I'm trying to migrate to Threejs, with a problem that only output is white box. What am I doing wrong?

```
import * as THREE from 'three';


// Fragment Shader
const fragmentShader = () => {
    return `
#ifdef GL_ES
precision lowp float;
#endif

uniform float u_time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main(void)
{
    vec2 uv = vUv;
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, uv);
}
`;
}

const vertexShader = () => {
    return `
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
`;
}


// object
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2);

var texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'image.png' );


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// CAMERA
var height = 10.0; // window.innerHeight;
var width = 10.0; // window.innerWidth;
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 5;

const uniforms = {
    time: { value: 1.0 },
    hue: { value: 0.0 },
    texture1: { value: texture1}
};

const planeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: vertexShader(),
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader(),
    uniforms: uniforms,
});

const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, planeMaterial);
scene.add(plane);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

There must be something wrong in the general setup, not particular functions (they are fine I guess).

Comment: There is a lot of code. Add `gl_FragColor = myVariable; return;` to test if your variables have the values you expect them to.

Comment: `v_texcoord = uv;` where do you set/add `uv` attribute to `geometry`?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I edited the code for clarity and removed non-crucial lines. @prisoner849
how can I add it to geometry? Is it not automatically defined with "const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2);"